# RuntimeError: Working outside of application context. with app.app_context() not resolving the issue

Tags: python, flask, multiprocessing

I am trying to run a time consuming loop by having a pool of processes work on it using `pool.map`. The loop is a part of a view function which I have  placed in a new function so that I can pass it to pool.map. But this throws the error -

> RuntimeError: Working outside of application context.
>
> This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed
>   to interface with the current application object in some way. To solve
>   this, set up an application context with app.app_context().  See the
>   documentation for more information.

I did place the method call in a `with app.app_context()` (as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34123343)). But the error didn't go away. Please tell me how I can resolve this issue.

```
@app.route('/some_url', methods= ['POST'])
def view_function ():
    start_time = time.time()
    data = request.get_json()
    a = round(data.get('a', '') * data.get('a', ''))
    b = round(data.get('b', '') * data.get('b', ''))
    c = round(data.get('c', '') * data.get('c', ''))
    d = round(data.get('d', '') * data.get('d', ''))

    a_id = select.get_id(data.get('property', ''), session['somedata'][1])
    some_list, a_ids, loc = AnotherClassInDifferentDir.get_list(a_id, session['somedata'][1])
    value = select.get_value(//some arguments)
```

This is where I use multiprocessing, and where I using `with app.app_context():` (This is a part of the same function, `view_function`) -

```
    with app.app_context():
        e = data.get('e', '')
        stuff = session['somedata'][1]
        pool = Pool(processes = 2)
        func = partial(loopTask,e, a_id, a_ids, a, b, c, d, loc, stuff)
        stuff_array = [(index, item) for index, item in enumerate(some_list)]
        print("stuff_array =", stuff_array)
        pool.map(func, stuff_array)
        pool.close()
        pool.join()

    print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
    return ''

def loopTask(e, a_ids, a, b, c, d, loc, stuff, stuff_item):

    index, s = stuff_item
    c_id = document_ids[index]
    done = AnotherClassInDifferentDir.work(s)
    f = AnotherClassInDifferentDir.more_work(done, a, b, c, d, loc)
    if f != '':
        update.update_work(//some arguments)
        g.cnxn.commit()
        if (moreDB.check(//some arguments) ==0):
            update.work(//some arguments)
            g.cnxn.commit()
    else:
        pass
```

I believe the `g.cnxn.commit()` is causing this issue since it is exposed by the application context but I'm not sure. Please help!

**EDIT**

`g.cnxn` is set in a different method with the decorator `@app.before_request`

```
@app.before_request
def connect_to_database():
    if request.endpoint != 'static':
        if not hasattr(g,'cnxn'):
            g.cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={{Some Driver}};config1={};config2={};Trusted_connection=yes'.format(app.config['config1'],app.config['config2']))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated in the Flask [docs](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/appcontext/#lifetime-of-the-context), the app context isn't available outside of a request which is what happens when the `loopTask` is run in a different process. Consider passing your app instance to the `loopTask` function and wrap the sections of the code under it that use the `g` namespace object inside your with block. 
Don't really need the `with` block inside of your `view_function` since an app context already exists during the request.

EDIT: Because we're setting up a db connection before each request, let's got with a `test_request_context`. You can read more about it [here](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/testing/#other-testing-tricks). It's meant for testing but for our purposes, it'll allow us to have a db connection in the spawned process.

```py
def loopTask(e, a_ids, a, b, c, d, loc, stuff, stuff_item, app):  # added app parameter 

    index, s = stuff_item
    c_id = document_ids[index]

    with app.test_request_context('/some_url'):
        app.preprocess_request()  # triggers 'connect_to_database'

        done = AnotherClassInDifferentDir.work(s)
        f = AnotherClassInDifferentDir.more_work(done, a, b, c, d, loc)
        if f != '':
            update.update_work(//some arguments)
            g.cnxn.commit()
            if (moreDB.check(//some arguments) ==0):
                update.work(//some arguments)
                g.cnxn.commit()
        else:
            pass
```

This then means the `with` block changes to:

```py
    e = data.get('e', '')
    stuff = session['somedata'][1]
    pool = Pool(processes = 2)
    func = partial(loopTask,e, a_id, a_ids, a, b, c, d, loc, stuff, stuff_item)
    stuff_array = [(index, item) for index, item in enumerate(some_list)]
    print("stuff_array =", stuff_array)
    pool.map(func, (stuff_array, app))  # passing the `app` Flask instance here
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

This should do the trick but ideally, we should have the db connection setup in a function we can reuse in our `loopTask`. That way, we'd not need the `test_request_context` and use `app_context` instead.

Comment: Can you please post some code/example to demonstrate "passing your app instance to the loopTask function and wrap the sections of the code under it that use the g namespace inside your with block"?

Comment: Sure @Flameofudun, I'll need to need where/how you set up `g.conxn` in your code.

Comment: Hey @Larry I've added that info in an edit in the question details

Comment: Updated @Flameofudun. Let me know if you run into more issues and we'll fix those too.