# email is not sended on flask, i get "app.app_context()" error

Tags: python, flask

i am trying to make a little server that when a light is turned on in some streaming then i got an email,

```
app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['MAIL_SERVER']='smtp.gmail.com'
app.config['MAIL_PORT'] = 465
app.config['MAIL_USERNAME'] = 'xxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com'
app.config['MAIL_PASSWORD'] = 'xxxxxxxxx'
app.config['MAIL_USE_TLS'] = False
app.config['MAIL_USE_SSL'] = True
mail = Mail(app)

stream = "rtsp://xxx:yyy@123.123.123.123/media.amp"
camera = cv2.VideoCapture(stream)
YEYE = ["none"]

def send_mail_ohyea(y,Y):
    if y != Y[-1]:
        print("cambio!",y,Y[-1])
        msg = Message('la luz se encendio', sender = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com', recipients = ['zzzzzzzzzzzzz@gmail.com'])
        msg.body = "la luz se encendio"
        mail.send(msg)

def img_estim(night, cam):
    
    is_light = np.mean(cam) > np.mean(night)+20
    return 'light' if is_light else 'dark'
    
def gen_frames():  
    while True:
        success, frame = camera.read()  # read the camera frame
        if not success:
            break
        else:
            
            filename_noche = "/home/workstationhp/flash_detect/pics/train/noche/noche.png"
            noche = imageio.imread(filename_noche, as_gray=True)
            ret, buffer = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)
            y = img_estim(noche, frame)
            send_mail_ohyea(y,YEYE)
            YEYE.append(img_estim(noche, frame))
            frame = buffer.tobytes()
           
            yield (b'--frame\r\n'
                   b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n')
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')
@app.route('/video_feed')
def video_feed():
    return Response(gen_frames(), mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

now when i run this code i get this error, i want to ask, what this means?(to my code) and how i can solve it?

> File
> "/home/workstationhp/anaconda3/envs/tf-gpu/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/globals.py",
> line 52, in _find_app
> raise RuntimeError(_app_ctx_err_msg)
> RuntimeError: Working outside of application context.
> This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed to interface with the current application object in some way.
> To solve this, set up an application context with app.app_context().
> See the documentation for more information.

thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/a/34123343/15011621

Comment: you are right! the context with app.app_context(): worked perfectly